# Show that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2-x\rangle$ is not a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I have a proposition which says that an ideal $I$ is a prime ideal in $R$ iff its quotient ring $R/I$ is a domain. I know that for an ideal to be a prime ideal, $xy\in I\implies x\in I\lor y\in I$. My thought is this: $x\notin \langle x^2-x\rangle$ and $x-1\notin \langle x^2-x\rangle$, but $x(x-1)=x^2-x\in \langle x^2-x\rangle$, so $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2-x\rangle$ is not a domain. Am I thinking this right?

Comment: The idea is correct.

Comment: @egreg Ok, cool. Is the execution wrong, though?

Comment: Not wrong, but well known and often asked again. $x^2-x=x(x-1)$ is reducible.

Comment: @KasperLarsen You just have to dress it up: proving the statement $x\notin(x^2-x)$, for instance (which is easy, but is necessary nonetheless).

Comment: @egreg I see, thank you!